# Zuul returns HTTP status 200 instead of 302

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a service called Backend (port: 9090) sitting behind Zuul (port: 8080).

The browser invokes a GET method on the Zuul, which does a redirect.

Sample invoke:  http://localhost:8080/testredirect

Result:

- Browser receives Http status = 200
- Browser URL:  http://localhost:8080/testredirect
- Browser shows: "Hello world"

Expected result:

- Browser should receive Http status = 302 and change URL, resulting in:
- Browser URL:  http://localhost:8080/hello
- Browser shows: "Hello world"

It seems Zuul is returning 200, hiding the redirect since its a proxy server.

How can I achieve 302 redirect in the browser, when the URL is defined in the GET method on the server side?

Here is the backend service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping
    public class Backend {
        @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello world";
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/testredirect")
        public RedirectView sayRandom() {
            return new RedirectView("/hello");
        }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration of the Zuul:

```
server:
  port: 8080
zuul:
  routes:
    core:
      sensitive-headers:
      path: /core/**
      url: http://localhost:9090/
```

Note: spring cloud -> Edgware.RELEASE

Comment: zuul just proxies the result, it wouldn't change the status. Are you sure there isn't an error happening or something else?

Comment: I didn't see exceptions. I'm getting the right content, but the URL in the browser is not correct. Browser doesn't see 302, rather it gets 200.

Comment: I don't understand, you're getting the right content? Can you provide a sample project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Your service isn't working as you expect. We have this exact scenario and if the service returns 302 then it's passed back through zuul just as you'd expect it to be.

Comment: I've tried to improve the explanation and add some very simple sample code.

Comment: We upgraded our spring cloud versions last week and we began seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality has changed in spring-boot release Edgeware.RELEASE.

In Edgeware.RELEASE:   returns 200, and the content of the page.

In Dalston.SR4:   returns 302 and the browser redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a bean in your Spring context.

```
@Bean 
public ApacheHttpClientFactory apacheHttpClientFactory() {
     return new ApacheHttpClientFactory() {
         @Override 
         public HttpClientBuilder createBuilder() {
             return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                     .disableContentCompression()
                     .disableCookieManagement()
                     .useSystemProperties()
                     .disableRedirectHandling();
         }
     }
 }
```